# Finding a good way to pass information through a callback with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, callback

I have some code which calls Google Maps asynchronously:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
directionsService.route(arg1, callback);
directionsService.route(arg2, callback);
directionsService.route(arg3, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
  // complex function here
}
```

Right now each callback results in a single piece of data which is stored in a global variable. The design has grown somewhat and now I'd like to include a parameter with each of the callbacks. But I can't do this directly, since I don't control `directionsService.route`. It also strikes me that this is already a roundabout way to handle the problem; I'd much rather pass `arg1, arg2, arg3` and their parameters to a function which can handle the async stuff and clean up when all have returned. Any suggestions on what is the best way to go about this?

I could dig my hole deeper by adding another global and updating it between calls. I could write a wrapper for directionsService.route which wraps it in another layer of callback indirection. I could try to bludgeon the callback format into one matching that required by a library like [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/). I could write several versions of my callback function, or replace it with a function generator. Are any of these options reasonable? Is there something better?

Honestly this is a small project and I don't need something that scales well, but just for my own peace of mind I'd like something unterrible and somewhat DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple code witch dispatch an event with the callback function. When the event is dispatch, you have a simply `eventListener`, with what ever parameters you want, witch call your big function.

This is my code:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

// Listen for the event.
var aParameter = 35;
window.addEventListener('build', function (e) { console.log("OK EVENT. With a prameter: " + aParameter); /* Now, call a function with parameters:*/ aFunction (aParameter); }, false);

directionsService.route(arg1, callback);

function callback() {
  console.log("OK CALLBACK.");
  var event = new Event('build');
  // Dispatch the event.
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function aFunction (parameter) {
  console.log (parameter);
}
```

You can also dispatch events with parameters like status with:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('build', { detail: elem.dataset.time });

function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log('The time is: ' + e.detail);
}
```

Consult the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) about event.

*Tell me if you have some questions.*